# Using Value of String variable to call an instance in vb.net winform

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls, instance

I have UserControl named for example 'aaa'

then i have variable:

> Dim a as String = "aaa"

Now, i declare

> Dim uc as UserControl = new aaa

my question is, can i write declaration above using value of variable a like below

> Dim uc as UserControl = new a

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using reflection (in the `System.Reflection`) namespace.  For instance:

```
Dim t As Type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType("namespace.aaa")
Dim o As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(t)
```

Notice that you will need the full type name, including the namespace, so you may need to concatenate that to your string, for instance:

```
Dim namespace As String = "MyNamespace"
Dim t As Type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType(namespace & "." & a)
Dim o As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(t)
```